# Computed property get returned twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to get the initials of the full name using computed properties but it returns `undefined` and tries to get the initials before it renders the full name as shown below

```
    computed: {
        user: function () {
            console.log(this.$store.state.user.name);
            //return this.$store.state.username.match(/[A-Z]/g).slice(0, 2).join('');
        }
    }
```

[image]

How to get this to work? like it doesn't call `match` function unless the full name is rendered?

Comment: please show the rest of the component - as well as the inital values of vuex store

Comment: you can use optional chaining to avoid checking for undefined

Comment: @DenisTsoi I just call the computed property in my template using `user` and my store.js file be like `user: {}`

Comment: @DenisTsoi how would I use this optional chaining thing?

Comment: What is your question here? The title and body of the question are not matching.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

`this.$store?.state?.user?.name`

Comment: `user` computed property returns `undefined` then it returns the full name and I can't call `match` function of undefined

Comment: Never mutate data in a `computed`! Computed are getters or getter/setters, when you provide both. If you want to mutate your data, do it using a method, not a `computed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the computed property is running twice, is once when the app is created, then once your data updates, running twice.

Best way to handle this is wherever your data is to change the computed property to check if the data is there, like so:

```
if(this.$store.state.user.name) return this.$store.state.user.name
```

Or if you are placing your computed property to the template, use a v-if:

```
v-if="$store.state.user.name"
```

Comment: You just saved my life. Thanks dude! ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can use Optional Chaining to handle undefined cases within your return statement.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
  computed: {
    user: function () {
      return this.$store.state?.user?.name?.match(/[A-Z]/g).slice(0, 2).join('');
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Support for the experimental syntax 'optionalChaining' isn't currently enabled`

Comment: its supported for chrome and ever green browsers -

Comment: Didn't work but thanks anyways. at least now I know what Optional Chaining is

Comment: its most likely that your babel doesn't have `optional chaining`

Comment: True I got it solved using `v-if="$store.state.user.name"`